# Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I want to use my local code connect to the remote hive by spark-sql .
this is my code :

```
package src.main.scala

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object hive_Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("spark://hadoop-s1:7077")
            .setAppName("kof-spark-hive")
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hadoop-s4:9083");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    sqlContext.sql("show databases").collect().foreach(println)
    sc.stop()

  }
}
```

But it break down and throw some exception:

```
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain src.main.scala.hive_Test
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/09/09 10:36:31 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/09/09 10:36:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/09 10:36:33 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:790)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2163)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2163)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2163)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:323)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test$.main(hive_Test.scala:22)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test.main(hive_Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
16/09/09 10:36:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: huaicui
16/09/09 10:36:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: huaicui
16/09/09 10:36:33 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(huaicui); users with modify permissions: Set(huaicui)
16/09/09 10:36:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54961.
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.140.200.141:54974]
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.140.200.141:54974]
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 54974.
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\huaicui\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-cf28f2a3-bae4-4566-8c06-492a85ca4554
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 945.5 MB
16/09/09 10:36:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.140.200.141:4040
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://hadoop-s1:7077...
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20160908223603-0005
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54994.
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54994
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.140.200.141:54994 with 945.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.140.200.141, 54994)
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/09/09 10:36:35 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
16/09/09 10:36:36 INFO HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 1.1.0
16/09/09 10:36:36 INFO ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0
16/09/09 10:36:36 INFO ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0-cdh5.8.0
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://hadoop-s4:9083
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
16/09/09 10:36:37 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getGroupsForUserCommand(Shell.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.createGroupExecutor(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.getGroups(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.fetchGroupList(Groups.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:208)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test$.main(hive_Test.scala:23)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test.main(hive_Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
16/09/09 10:36:37 WARN Hive: Failed to register all functions.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test$.main(hive_Test.scala:23)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test.main(hive_Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1501)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2263)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.getGroups(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.fetchGroupList(Groups.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:208)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    ... 41 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test$.main(hive_Test.scala:23)
    at src.main.scala.hive_Test.main(hive_Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:513)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:201)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1501)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2263)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.getGroups(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.fetchGroupList(Groups.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups$GroupCacheLoader.load(Groups.java:208)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    ... 41 more
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.140.200.141:4040
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\huaicui\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-904b401c-2283-4f95-a90f-0cc97dcae00e
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\huaicui\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-69a836bb-71f1-4db9-968b-5ff983ad5bea
16/09/09 10:36:37 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found that the exception is marketed at this line :    val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

I try to connect to hive by spark-shell , and it works fine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are running on Windows machine and this is failing with below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

Please download "winutils.exe" file from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils and keep inside one folder. Set HADOOP_HOME environment variable pointing to this folder path.

Comment: What error did you get after using winutils.exe? The error "Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe" is thrown because of missing "winutils.exe". Please check http://teknosrc.com/spark-error-java-io-ioexception-could-not-locate-executable-null-bin-winutils-exe-hadoop-binaries/

Comment: OK ,  it work fine. just because that I don't set an environment :System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hadoop-s4:9083");  Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer so it will be helpful for SO users in future.